# React Native passing data in auth fuction

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, parameter-passing, constants

im new in react native and i try to passing data from my login class to a auth function but it dont work.

This is my Auth function

```
function auth(username, password) {
fetch('http://192.168.178.26:8000/auth/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })

})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        saveToken(res.token);
        console.log(res.token);
        props.navigation.navigate('Home');

    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Constructor

```
    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        isReady: false,
        username: '',
        password: '',
    }

    this.auth = auth(this.state.username, this.state.password)

...more code

    render() {

    const {password} = this.state.password;
    const {username} = this.state.username;
```

My Text Inputs and the login button

```
 <TextInput
  placeholder='Email'
  ...
  value={username}/>

  <TextInput placeholder='Password'
  ...
  value={password}/>

  <TapGestureHandler>
  <Animated.View style={style.button} >
  <Text style={{ ... onPress={this.auth}>Anmelden</Text>
```

I work on this for days now and googled hours but i cant find a solution. Can you please help me?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Is your state updating?

```
<TextInput
  value={this.state.username}
  placeholder="Username"
  onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ username: value })
/>
```

Comment: I tried this but now i lose the focus on my TextInputs every time 'setState' is called.